# how to solve 'zipimporter' object has no attribute 'find_module'. Did you mean: 'load_module'?

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-mysql

I was working on flask application and while running an application while connecting with mysql database i am getting this error.

I was trying to install package in flask application in vs code but whenever i was installing any package i am getting zipimporter error .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.